# Сортировка структуры точек с помощью sort

Tags: c++, сортировка, c++11

У меня есть структура точки:

```
struct Point  
{  
    double x;  
    double y;  
};
```

У меня есть два массива этих точек, один из которых (`ans`) нужно отсортировать сначала по иксу, потом по игреку:

```
 Point p[51],ans[400000];
```

По аналогии с примером, который нашел здесь для целочисленных значений структуры, попробовал написать для своего случая:

```
sort(ans,ans+sochcnt+1, [&](Point &a, Point &b){ return RealLessEq(a.x,b.x) });
sort(ans,ans+sochcnt+1, [&](Point &a, Point &b){ return RealLessEq(a.y,b.y) });
```

где `RealLessEq` - процедура сравнения двух вещественных чисел (возвращает `true`, если `a<=b`):

```
bool RealLessEq(double a, double b)
{
    if ((a-b)<=Eps)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

где `double Eps=1e-6;`
  Компилятор на строку
`sort(ans,ans+sochcnt+1, [&](Point &a, Point &b){ return RealLessEq(a.x,b.x) });`
выдает ошибку
`expected ';' before '}' token|`

Подскажите, как это сделать корректно.

Comment: Что означает "отсортировать сначала по иксу, потом по игреку:"? То есть после первой сортировки выполняется вторая сортировка, которая полностью перечеркивает первую сортировку?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ну, вам ответили вполне понятно - вы забыли точку с запятой:

```
sort(ans,ans+sochcnt+1, [&](Point &a, Point &b){ return RealLessEq(a.x,b.x); });
                                                                           ^
```

Но есть еще замечания. Даже не знаю, с какого начать...
*отсортировать сначала по иксу, потом по игреку* - это как? Просто отсортировать по `x`, поработать, а потом еще раз - по `y`, потеряв сортировку по `x`? Или при равных `x` должны быть отсортированы по `y`? Вы решаете задачу в первом понимании, но не во втором! Чтобы решать во втором варианте - должна быть функция, сравнивающая `x`, *а при равенстве* - `y`. Примерно

```
[](const Point&a, const Point&b) 
    { return (a.x < b.x) ? true : (a.x > b.x) ? false : (a.y < b.y); }
```

Далее, если у вас `sochcnt` элементов в массиве, то и вызывать сортировку надо как

```
sort(ans,ans+sochcnt, ...
```

Конечно, если их `sochcnt+1`, то у вас все верно, тут я просто не знаю.

И еще - компаратор возвращает результат сравнения **меньше**, а не *меньше или равно*. Строго меньше. Если ему понадобится проверка на равенство, алгоритм ее выполнит сам, как `!((a<b)||(b<a))`.

Answer (score 0):

В обоих этих предложениях

```
sort(ans,ans+sochcnt+1, [&](Point &a, Point &b){ return RealLessEq(a.x,b.x) });
                                                                          ^^      
sort(ans,ans+sochcnt+1, [&](Point &a, Point &b){ return RealLessEq(a.y,b.y) });
                                                                          ^^
```

вы внутри тела лямбда выражений забыли указать точку с запятой.

Данная функция неверная

```
bool RealLessEq(double a, double b)
{
    if ((a-b)<=Eps)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

так как сравнение должно удовлетворять условию (так называемое ***strict weak ordering***), при котором, например, выражение !RealLessEq( x, x ) должно иметь значение `true`.  То есть должна иметь проверка на строгое неравенство.

Поэтому по крайней мере эту функцию, если она используется в сортировке, следует написать как

```
bool RealLessEq(double a, double b)
{
    return a < b;
}
```

Для получения указателей на начало массива и на конец массива, то есть на место после последнего элемента массива, чтобы задать диапазон итераторов, можно использовать стандартные функции `std::begin` и `std::end`, которые объвоены в заголовке `<iterator>`.

Вызов стандартного алгоритма будет выглядеть следующим образом

```
std::sort(std::begin(ans), std::end(ans),
    [](const Point &a, const Point &b) 
    { 
        return RealLessEq(a.x, b.x); 
    });
```

или для сортировки по вторым координатам

```
std::sort(std::begin(ans), std::end(ans),
    [](const Point &a, const Point &b) 
    { 
        return RealLessEq(a.y, b.y); 
    });
```

Вот демонстрационная программа

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

bool RealLessEq(double a, double b)
{
    return a < b;
}

int main()
{
    struct Point
    {
        double x;
        double y;
    };

    Point ans[] = { { 2, 3 }, { 1, 4 }, { 3, 0 } };

    std::sort(std::begin(ans), std::end(ans),
        [](const Point &a, const Point &b) 
        { 
            return RealLessEq(a.x, b.x); 
        });

    for (const auto &p : ans)
    {
        std::cout << p.x << ' ' << p.y << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::sort(std::begin(ans), std::end(ans),
        [](const Point &a, const Point &b)
        {
            return RealLessEq(a.y, b.y);
        });

    for (const auto &p : ans)
    {
        std::cout << p.x << ' ' << p.y << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль

```
1 4
2 3
3 0

3 0
2 3
1 4
```

В принципе функция `RealLessEq` для такого простого сравнения чисел с плавающей запятой не нужна. Вы могли бы записать лямбда вырадение, например, в виде

```
    std::sort(std::begin(ans), std::end(ans),
        [](const Point &a, const Point &b) 
        { 
            return a.x < b.x; 
        });
```

Если вам нужно отсортировать точки по `x`, а затем внутри этой сортировки по `y`, то делается это просто с помощью стандартной функции `std::tie`, объявленной в заголовке `<tuple>`. Например,

```
std::sort(std::begin(ans), std::end(ans),
    [](const Point &a, const Point &b)
    {
        return std::tie( a.x, a.y ) < std::tie( b.x, b.y );
    });
```